# L'Hospital's rule in the other direction

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are differentiable functions in  $]0,1[$ and it is given that $f$ and $g$ are continuous in  $[0,1]$ and we also get that $g(0)=f(0)=0$, is then the following statement, "$\,\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= A \implies \lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}= A"$,  true?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577597/does-lhôpitals-work-the-other-way

Comment: Try $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=x+x^2 \sin(1/x)$.

Comment: @WimC yes but g(0)=0, so we get 0+0*sin(1/0) and i don't know if we can assume that this equals zero

Comment: $g$ extends to a continuous function on $[0,1]$. Note that $\lvert g(x) \rvert \leq x+x^2$ on $(0,1)$.